# how to configure customer converter/formatter and which to use in Spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to bind a nested object to a form select list. It's a simple Product => MediaSet relationship.

I read a few blog posts etc. that suggested to use a custom Formatter class to convert between the select list value and the type.

But I'm having trouble figuring out how the configuration works. I've been using the java configuration classes so far.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is Formatter the right interface to use? I also read about Converter, and it sounds like maybe I should be using that instead.
2. How do I register the custom formatter using java configuration?

My config class looks like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mvc")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

....

   @Bean
    public ConversionService conversionService() {
        DefaultFormattingConversionService bean = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
        bean.addFormatter(new ImageSetFormatter());
        return bean;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh never mind, I figured it out and it was actually very easy, but I'll leave the question here in case someone else is looking for it.

There's a method in the super class to register it:

To register the customer formatter, just replace above with this instead:

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


 ...

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {
        formatterRegistry.addFormatter(new ImageSetFormatter());
    }
}
```